# Payment gateway choice

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, payment-gateway

I have developed iphone app now for payment option I am not able to makeup my mind which is best 1. PayPal 2. Braintree.

I would like to save users payment info every time usage. So only one time user have to fill up the info and I can use next time saved info for payment. Like UBER app doing... Is this possible on mobile app end?

Comment: yes it is possible.

Comment: I recommend you change your question so you specifically mean saving card and billing details.

Saving name, login details etc. is the scope for another question

This is why the question was downvoted

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use paypal for saving cards with their rest api

Below is the paypal code from the api samples and docs site at 
http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/

```
// # Create Credit Card Sample
// You can store credit card details securely
// with PayPal. You can then use the returned
// Credit card id to process future payments.
// API used: POST /v1/vault/credit-card


require __DIR__ . '/../bootstrap.php';
use PayPal\Api\CreditCard;

// ### CreditCard
// A resource representing a credit card that is 
// to be stored with PayPal.
$card = new CreditCard();
$card->setType("visa")
    ->setNumber("4917912523797702")
    ->setExpireMonth("11")
    ->setExpireYear("2019")
    ->setCvv2("012")
    ->setFirstName("Joe")
    ->setLastName("Shopper");

// ### Additional Information
// Now you can also store the information that could help you connect
// your users with the stored credit cards.
// All these three fields could be used for storing any information that could help merchant to point the card.
// However, Ideally, MerchantId could be used to categorize stores, apps, websites, etc.
// ExternalCardId could be used for uniquely identifying the card per MerchantId. So, combination of "MerchantId" and "ExternalCardId" should be unique.
// ExternalCustomerId could be userId, user email, etc to group multiple cards per user.
$card->setMerchantId("MyStore1");
$card->setExternalCardId("CardNumber123" . uniqid());
$card->setExternalCustomerId("123123-myUser1@something.com");

// For Sample Purposes Only.
$request = clone $card;

// ### Save card
// Creates the credit card as a resource
// in the PayPal vault. The response contains
// an 'id' that you can use to refer to it
// in future payments.
// (See bootstrap.php for more on `ApiContext`)
try {
    $card->create($apiContext);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    // NOTE: PLEASE DO NOT USE RESULTPRINTER CLASS IN YOUR ORIGINAL CODE. FOR SAMPLE ONLY
    ResultPrinter::printError("Create Credit Card", "Credit Card", null, $request, $ex);
    exit(1);
}

// NOTE: PLEASE DO NOT USE RESULTPRINTER CLASS IN YOUR ORIGINAL CODE. FOR SAMPLE ONLY
 ResultPrinter::printResult("Create Credit Card", "Credit Card", $card->getId(), $request, $card);

return $card;
```

For more information @https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest-vault-overview/

Answer (score -1):

You can use Paypal for your requirement and paypal directly doesnt give any credentials either you have to access the tokens for that particular user when it will fill the information. That token is provided by paypal(just think it is like a remember me in your app).

Note :I itself not implemented this but i think this must be the approach.